# Translate .data section code from nasm to gas?

Tags: assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler

Translate .data section code from nasm to gas.
nasm data section:

```
TssDesc:
    dw TssLen-1
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 0x89
    db 0
    db 0
    dq 0

Tss:
    dd 0
    dq 0xffff800000190000
    times 88 db 0
    dd TssLen

TssLen: equ $-Tss
```

my try to translate to gas:

```
TssDesc:
    .word TssLen-1
    .word 0
    .byte 0
    .byte 0x89
    .byte 0
    .byte 0
    .quad 0

Tss:
    .long 0
    .quad 0xffff800000190000
    .fill 88,8,0
    .long TssLen

TssEnd:
    .set TssLen, TssEnd - Tss
```

Is it right?

And Can TssLen be used(.long TssLen) before .set(.set TssLen, TssEnd - Tss)?

Comment: `.fill 88,8,0` is wrong. Note that the original has `db`. So it's just `.fill 88`.

Comment: Coding style: I'd tend to use `.equ` to define integer constants, or `TssLen = . - Tss`, by analogy to NASM's `equ` keyword.  `.set` is a synonym in GAS, but I prefer not to use it for defined-once assemble-time constants that I don't actually want to or care about seeing in the symbol table in the .o.

Comment: But if I write .equ TssLen = . - Tss it gives me an error boot64.S:25: Error: expected comma after "TssLen".